# incorrect operation of edit btn in js

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie and I have a problem with editing. How can I change the elements of the current block? because when you click, it is edited in one block. Please share the code on how to fix this. thx)

```js
const editBtn = document.createElement('button');
editBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Edit'));
editBtn.classList.add('board__edit');
editBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const items = document.querySelector('.board__stage-card');


  if (editBtn.textContent == 'Edit') {
    editBtn.textContent = 'Ok';
    items.contentEditable = true;
    items.focus();
  } else {
    editBtn.textContent = 'Edit';
    items.contentEditable = false;
  }

});
```

Comment: What is the 'correct' operation you are thinking?

Comment: I only edit the first element of the first block, even if I click the edit button in the second block, for example

Comment: Do you need every edit button only enable edit of the element next to it, or 1 or all button for all blocks? If it is 1 or all button for all blocks, you should first use `querySelectorAll` to get all blocks, then change the if statement to loop

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how to do this, let me tell you how it looks

Comment: https://codepen.io/streetdrunker/pen/eYWKEPd

Comment: So, it is one-to-one. In such case your HTML is need. Please provide it.

Comment: did I give you a link or do you need all the html?

Comment: Please kindly provide the minimal code. I only want to know the structure to suggest a code fit you well